# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> in to_date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As the error says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\fakepath\pythonCSV\main.py", line 84, in <module>
    print(to_date(df['start_time']))
  File "E:\fakepath\pythonCSV\main.py", line 75, in to_date
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000).strftime("%d-%b-%Y"), "%d-%b-%Y")
  File "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 141, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

And my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
col = client['right']['abcde']

listFileNames = (glob.glob(r"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Book1.csv"))

# print(len(listFileNames))

cols = ["start_time", "end_time", "source_Ip", "source_Mac", "destination_Ip", "destination_Mac"]


def get_merged_data_frame(list_file_names, p_index_col=False, p_header=None, columns=None):
    if columns is None:
        columns = cols
    if len(list_file_names) == 1:
        return pd.read_csv(list_file_names[0], index_col=p_index_col, header=p_header, low_memory=False,
                           names=columns,
                           usecols=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
    else:
        df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, index_col=p_index_col, header=p_header, low_memory=False, names=columns,
                                         usecols=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
                             for f in list_file_names)
        concatenated_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
        return concatenated_df


def to_date(x):
    return datetime.strftime(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x)/1000).strftime("%d-%b-%Y"), "%d-%b-%Y")




df = get_merged_data_frame(listFileNames)
print(df)
df['start_data'] = df['start_time'].apply(to_date)
print(to_date(df['start_time']))
print(type(df))
print(df)
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print(data)
col.insert_many(data)
```

I have tried many solutions, I have tried but I don't where I have put is it right?
Many of the solution says to use `.astype(int)` or `.astype(float)`

```
df['start_data'] = df['start_time'].astype(int)
```

This `df['start_time']` looks like this

```
0       1617213592022005000
1       1617213592064079000  
Name: start_time, Length: 3960, dtype: int64
```

But it seems to be wrong...

Thanks for Any Answers...

Comment: What `df['start_time']` looks like? `[1622332800000.0, 1622347200000.0, 1622361600000.0, ...]`?

Comment: for this i have edited the question. please take a look

Comment: `df['start_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])`

Comment: did find something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for a string representation (like your function `to_date`)

```
df['start_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], unit='ns') \
                     .dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
```

```
>>> df
            start_time   start_data
0  1617213592022005000  31-Mar-2021
1  1617213592064079000  31-Mar-2021
```

Comment: Thanks but now i am getting this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '31-Mar-2021'`

Comment: What is the code line that raises this exception?

Comment: At this line error rise after modification    `df['start_data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], unit='ns').dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y").astype(int).apply(to_date)`

Comment: You don't need `.astype(int).apply(to_date)` and your function `to_date` anymore. I updated my answer to better understanding.